# regex ms word 2013 white line

Tags: ms-word

I am searching on how I can find a replace following:

[white line]

[integer]

[white line]

so anything i would like to copy / replace anything that: has a new line followed by an integer on the new line followed by another new line.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never really worked with regex before but I figure I'd give it a go

```
^13{2}<[0-9]@>^13{2}
```

Since this is in Ms-word ^13 finds line breaks and 2 line breaks consecutively will get you a white line, <[0-9]@> is finding a group of integers and then it finds 2 more line breaks for another white line.

Make sure to turn on wildcards!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this regex expression

```
\s*[0-9]\s*
```

Where \s* for [white line]
        [0-9] for [integer]

Comment: In MS WORD 13 for some reason \s* searched for letter 's' in text.